# Shut off Facebook Windows in the lower right hand corner?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

In Facebook is there a way to disable the new windows that display in the lower right hand corner of your browser in Google Chrome on OSX?

[image]

Comment: While you'll likely get an answer here, I feel like this should be on webapps...

Comment: I am down, but I do not have permissions to move it there. Do you?